# DataGridViewRow count

Tags: c#, visual-studio

**Logic**

```
If `rows` > 0
 loop `rows` {
  if `row Name value` equal `db Name column`
   - increase value
  else
   // it adds new row if db record is not already in grid view
   - add new
 }
else
// Happen only once for first input (when there is no row)
- add new
```

That's the logic I'm trying to build, but I have repeating rows issue (bug)

**Screenshot**

[image: one]

**Code**

```
// database name column
String searchValue = dt.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString();

if (selectedItems.RowCount > 0)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in selectedItems.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue))
        {
            // increase qty
            row.Cells["QtyH"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Value) + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            // Add new row
            selectedItems.Rows.Add(new string[] {
                dt.Rows[i]["Id"].ToString(),
                dt.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString(),
                "1",
                dt.Rows[i]["SellPrice"].ToString(),
                (item.Price * item.Qty).ToString()
            });
        }
    }
}
else
{
    // Add new row
    selectedItems.Rows.Add(new string[] {
        dt.Rows[i]["Id"].ToString(),
        dt.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString(),
        "1",
        dt.Rows[i]["SellPrice"].ToString(),
        (item.Price * item.Qty).ToString()
    });
}
```

> PS: `selectedItems` is name of my `DataGridView`

**Questions**

1. How to fix repeating bug

Comment: How is i incremented? dt.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString(); Try giving searchValue as "Table" or "Lamp"

Comment: @abhinavpratap all my code is inside this loop `for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                            {..}`

Comment: As abhinav said, check what your searchValue actually is while debugging. Logically the only reason I can think of is that value isnt coming back with something you expect. If the value truly is correct I would look into what is coming back with row.Cells[1].Value. That expression might also not be returning the value you expect.

Comment: For an existing row where the search is not found in index 1 (Name) it will add a new row. The first time there will be one row added (default row). Then you will hit the first block where check for the search value is made. The search ist not found a second row is added. Tehn you have 2 rows. The second row is checked, a third row is added an so on. Then this repeats for every remaining rows always adding new row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic fails when Lamp is not equal to Table. As you are looping all rows in DataGridView.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in selectedItems.Rows)
```

So, suppose your selectedItems already has 2 rows (Table and Lamp). Now searchValue has "Lamp" in it. You are looping for all the rows in selectedItems.
For first iteration "Table" will not be equal to "Lamp" and will go in else and add "Lamp" row.

Logic should be like below:

```
    If `rows` > 0
{
 isMatched = false;
 loop `rows` {
  if `row Name value` equal `db Name column`
   - set isMatched to true
   - increase value
 }
if(!isMatched)
 {
   // it adds new row if db record is not already in grid view
   - add new
 }
}
else
// Happen only once for first input (when there is no row)
- add new
```

Comment: so what do you suggest?

Comment: Insert after the foreach loop no else condition or you can add another variable which is true when there is match. Insert based on that variable value.

Comment: You mean I remove `else {..}` part?

Comment: Thank you that `isMatched` variable did the fix

Answer (score 0):

Do a caching into a temporary list (both 2 blocks):

```
// Add new row
        selectedItems.Rows.Add(new string[] {
            dt.Rows[i]["Id"].ToString(),
            dt.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString(),
            "1",
            dt.Rows[i]["SellPrice"].ToString(),
            (item.Price * item.Qty).ToString()
        });
```

into a temporary list and add the newly once (temporaray list) at the end!

```
If `rows` > 0
 loop `rows` {
  if `row Name value` equal `db Name column`
   - increase value
  else
   // it adds new row if db record is not already in grid view
   - add new to temp list
 }
else
 // Happen only once for first input (when there is no row)
 - add new to temp list

at last:
 foreach (var value in tempList)
 {
   selectedItems.Rows.Add(new string[] {
                value.Id.ToString(),
                value.Name,
                "1",
                value.SellPrice.ToString(),
                (value.Price * value..Qty).ToString()
            });
 }
```

Just a assumption - give it a try!

Regards

Comment: how can I `caching into a temporary list`?  sorry, still newbie

Comment: add a class with the properties like Id etc. i.e. "MyItem". Make a List<MyItem> list = new List<MyItem>(); Add your items to it.